# Deleting Rockwell PanelView Files Remotely

Tags: remote-debugging

Can anyone please help me with deleting Rockwell PanelView Files (.mer) Remotely. I can upload and download files remotely using HMI Transfer Utility. But now I want delete the old files in there remotely. Is there a way I can do it?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge ... unless ... you are running a newer Panelview Plus 7 that has VNC server installed (and configured). Also the Panelview CE versions allow remote VNC connectivity.
Here is a link that details the VNC setup:
https://theautomationblog.com/enable-and-use-vnc-on-the-panelview-plus-7/